# Topological Insulator

Tags: crystals, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators, topological-phase, chern-simons-theory

What effect on the Brillouin zone (torus) after applying the magnetic field? As in real space, pressure deforms the torus and up to a certain pressure, this remains invariant topologically. Similar to what happens with Brillouin zone. And what is the connection of topology in the Brillouin zone and band diagram?

Comment: Welcome to phys.SE! In order for people to help you, please define the relevant concepts, and make clear what you're asking. As it stands the question is extremely unclear and impossible to answer.